# Magento 2 quick search by part of the SKU

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a product with the SKU `PC04988#1` If I search with full SKU(PC04988#1) it's returning the product. 
How would I get the products which matches the sku for example,
If I enter `04988` I want it to return all the products which matches the string  04988 (%SKU%).

Comment: @Down voters, can you please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Magento 1, Magento 2 does not provide such configuration like search type like, fultext, and combine. Instead of it Magento 2 provides Fulltext Mysql Search Engine.

Comment: How to achieve partial SKU search in magento 2.

Comment: For that, you need to use either elastic search or solr search provided by Magento 2.